# Session flash message timeout in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created flash message in Laravel page using controller. It's showing well but need to add timeout in flash message

```
if($location_vaidation>0){
     $material_details->location_id=$requested_location;     
     }
     else{
        Session::flash('success', 'please fill the form with valid data');
        return Redirect::to('request');
        exit;           
     }
```

In view page

```
@if( Session::has("success") )
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-block" role="alert">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  {{ Session::get("success") }}
 </div>
 @endif
 @if( Session::has("error") )
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block" role="alert">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
  {{ Session::get("error") }}
 </div>
 @endif
 <div class="flash-message"></div>
```

Comment: what timeout ? you meant to fadeout the flash message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this using Jquery function

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("div.alert").remove();
    }, 5000 ); // 5 secs

});
```

Comment: Would you show how to integrate this into his existing code?

Answer (score 6):

In the header add this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

then use it in blade as following:

```
@if (session($messageKey))
    <div x-data="{show: true}" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000)" x-show="show">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session($messageKey) }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: it works for me, thanks. I think it's better than facing to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

you might want this to autoclose / fadeout your alert messages, This will be a smooth fading , and you do require jquery

```
$(".alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(".alert").slideUp(500);
});
```